# How to load modal first when screen loads

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a modal component called **Modal.js**  and a main page component called **Apps.js**. What i want to achieve is, how can i load the `modal box in modal.js` as i navigate in to `Apps.js`. i.e I want to call Modal.js component first in my `Apps.js` component.  The modal box should trigger and pop up once any user tries to load page `Apps.js`. How do i achieve that ?

PS: New to React

**Modal.Js**

```
function Transition(props) {
   return <Slide direction="up" {...props} />;
}

export default class AlertDialogSlide extends React.Component {

   state = {
      open: false,
   };

   handleClose = () => {
      this.setState({ open: false });
   };

   render() {
      return (
         <div>
            <Dialog
               open={this.state.open}
               TransitionComponent={Transition}
               keepMounted
               onClose={this.handleClose}
               aria-labelledby="alert-dialog-slide-title"
               aria-describedby="alert-dialog-slide-description"
            >
               <DialogTitle id="alert-dialog-slide-title">

               </DialogTitle>
               <DialogContent>
               </DialogContent>

            </Dialog>
         </div>
      );
   }
}
```

**Apps.JS**

```
class Carts extends Component {

 componentDidMount(){

 }
```

}
**Image**

[image]

Comment: Set `state = {open: true};`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass your open state via props.

You can do the following code into your modal file:

```
componentDidMount () {
    this.setState({open: this.props.modalOpen})
}
```

Then into your App.js or another file, you just do:

```
<AlertDialogSlide modalOpen={true} />
```

Comment: shouldn't `modalOpen={true}` come from state, you won't be able to close that modal.

Comment: Nope, you pass the value via props, you update the state not the props after. ;) 
If you do, `<Dialog open={this.props.modalOpen} ... >` the modal won't be closed. States are mutable and props not

Comment: so how are you going to update `{true}` to `false`?

Comment: His function handleClose obviously. ^^

Comment: When i load the page `Apps.js`, the modal form doesn't pop up.

Comment: Replace componentDidMount with componentWillMount or can you create a snippet [here](https://codesandbox.io/)

Comment: `componentWillMount` is deprecated

Comment: @RadonirinaMaminiaina check the image for the error i am getting when i add `<AlertDialogSlide modalOpen={true} />`